# Magento connect cant install extension but manual install works

Tags: magento-connect

I am trying to install a magento extension via connect and i keep getting the following error.

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
'./app/etc' already exists
```

If i unzip the extension i can easily do a manual install and it works perfectly.

Did anything change between 1.8 and 1.9 that causes this problem ?

I also have write access to the directories.

Edit: I am trying to install this on CE 1.9

My package.xml was missing a few details this was my problem

Comment: I had problems with my magneto connect as well. Its best to have the latest version.

Comment: I figured out the problem, my package.xml file was missing a file element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

To resolve this problem just navigate to `Settings` and find `Magento Connect Channel Protocol:`

You have to change it from HTTP to `FTP`!

This will resolve your problem.

Tested and working, please if it works for you mark my answer as an answer for your question!

Comment: If this is the real answer, I vote that error message to be the worst diagnostic ever.

Comment: I figured out the problem, my package.xml file was missing a file element.